# Error: Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)

Tags: sql, group-by, firebird

I am using Firebird SQL. The below mentioned query returns 4 rows as shown in the figure.

```
    SELECT a.EPS_ID,b.C_NAME,c.AY_YR_NAME,d.S_NAME,e.E_NAME
FROM 
    TBLEXAMPLANNER_S_MSB a, 
    TBLCLASS_MSB b, 
    TBLACADEMICYEAR_MSB c, 
    TBLSUBJECTS_MSB d, 
    TBLEXAMTYPE_MSB e
WHERE 
    a.EPS_CLASS_ID=b.C_ID 
AND a.EPS_SESSION_ID=c.AY_ID 
AND a.EPS_SUB_ID=d.S_ID 
AND a.EPS_PE_ID=e.E_ID
```

[image: click to view image]

I want it to return only 1(one) row like

```
EPS_ID     C_NAME    AY_YR_NAME   S_NAME   E_NAME
---------------------------------------------------
7          5         2016-2017    English  FA1
```

I am using the following query but it does not work.

```
SELECT a.EPS_ID,MAX(b.C_NAME) AS XT,c.AY_YR_NAME,d.S_NAME,e.E_NAME
FROM 
    TBLEXAMPLANNER_S_MSB a, 
    TBLCLASS_MSB b, 
    TBLACADEMICYEAR_MSB c, 
    TBLSUBJECTS_MSB d, 
    TBLEXAMTYPE_MSB e
WHERE 
    a.EPS_CLASS_ID=b.C_ID 
AND a.EPS_SESSION_ID=c.AY_ID 
AND a.EPS_SUB_ID=d.S_ID 
AND a.EPS_PE_ID=e.E_ID
GROUP BY a.EPS_ID,d.S_NAME
```

The error message is :

> Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)

Comment: Did you try SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: i am also not able to make DISTINCT work with my query :(

Comment: As the error message says, you need list to any columns that are used in the `SELECT` list (that are not aggregates) in the `GROUP BY` expression

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: You need to use all select column in `group by` as well

Comment: @bharatpatidar, the opposite... list selected columns in the group by as well.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: How do you know which `EPS_ID` you want returned in your single desired row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usage of `GROUP BY` makes the engine *group* the records for you. To do grouping, you have to give advice to the RDBMS for **each** column, what it should do.

- Group it? -> Add column to `GROUP BY-Clause`
- Not group it? -> ok, what else?

  - ignore the column? remove it from your select-clause
  - Sum it? -> use `SUM(mycol)`
  - other aggregation functions can be found in the [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs.html)

Additionally: In your case you try to group by `EPS_ID`, which is unique in each row. So a **grouping** by that column will return all rows, because there is nothing to group by. To group records, they have to have the **same** value.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Your problem is that *all* unaggregated columns need to be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a.EPS_ID, MAX(b.C_NAME) AS XT, c.AY_YR_NAME, d.S_NAME, e.E_NAME
FROM TBLEXAMPLANNER_S_MSB a JOIN 
     TBLCLASS_MSB b
     ON a.EPS_CLASS_ID = b.C_ID JOIN
     TBLACADEMICYEAR_MSB c
     ON a.EPS_SESSION_ID = c.AY_ID JOIN
     TBLSUBJECTS_MSB d
     ON a.EPS_SUB_ID = d.S_ID JOIN 
     TBLEXAMTYPE_MSB e
     ON a.EPS_PE_ID = e.E_ID
GROUP BY a.EPS_ID, c.AY_YR_NAME, d.S_NAME, e.E_NAME;
```

Note:  I would also recommend that you use table abbreviations for table aliases.  So, `ep` for `TBLEXAMPLANNER_S_MSB` instead of `a`.  Arbitrary table aliases make the query hard to follow.

Comment: Thanks @gordon but it still shows me 4 rows as shown in the attached image

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT a.EPS_ID,c.AY_YR_NAME,d.S_NAME,e.E_NAME,MAX(b.C_NAME) AS XT ...
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.